# MySQL filter query?

Tags: mysql, sql

At the moment i have a query which counts the number of records dependent on country, and gives me a list something like:

- UK = 400
- Spain = 350
- etc...

I have now added in another coloumn for language as some countries have different languages e.g. Switzerland_Italian.

What would be the best way to amend my query so that if the country has different languages(as some don't) it will count these seperately in my list, so it would look something like:

- UK = 400
- Spain = 350
- Switzerland = 200
- Switzerland_Italian = 50

Would this need a subquery? The query i have at the moment is, i have added in the new lang coloumn:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS `count`,
  `region`,
  `lang`,
  DATE(NOW()) AS `week_ending` 
FROM
  mydata.table 
WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) 
  AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY `region`,
  DATE(NOW()) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to GROUP BY both region and lang, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`region`, `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` 
FROM mydata.table 
WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY `region`, `lang`, DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS `count`,
CONCAT( `region`,'_',`lang`),  
  `region`,
  `lang`,
  DATE(NOW()) AS `week_ending` 
FROM
  mydata.table 
WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) 
  AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY `region`,`lang`,
  DATE(NOW()) ;
```